# Php htaccess ignore repated source fails to enabled

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-reporting, php-ini

I am setting up my htaccess and tried to switch from display_errors to log_errors .. I got the log_errors and error_log working, so now I get errors logged into phpLogfile.txt. But I now want to get rid of the iterating messages. That's why I tried to enable ignore_repeated_errors and ignore_repeated_source.

I put this line of code in my script:

```
  require_once('stupid.php')
```

and of course this gives an error but the error will be logged over and over again.

I tried several alternatives like:

```
php_flag ignore_repeated_source 1
php_flag ignore_repeated_source on
php_flag ignore_repeated_source ON
php_flag ignore_repeated_source On
```

Since php.net says this setting is changeable as PHP_INI_ALL there must be a mistake on my site.
Am I missing something?

```
php_value error_reporting 2047
php_value display_errors 1
php_value log_errors 1
php_value error_log C:\xampp\htdocs\html\zillion_strato\phpLogfile\phpLogfile.txt

# disable repeated error logging
 php_value ignore_repeated_errors on
 php_value ignore_repeated_source on

 # save last error msg in variable
 php_flag track_errors on

 #protect/prevent looking up the path 
 <Files C:\xampp\htdocs\html\zillion_strato\phpLogfile\phpLogfile.txt>
 Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
 </Files>
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the exact variety of non-workingness?

Answer (score 0):

I see you've tried lots of random stuff and are apparently not getting clear feedback from the server so I think I'd better give you some tips (rather that just some code to copy to paste blindly).

Let's have a look at the relevant documentation:

- The [Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.php) section offers most of the relevant details (though I admit it could use a short introduction).
- Since you want per-directory changes and your question suggests you're running PHP as Apache module, details can be found at [Running PHP as an Apache module](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#configuration.changes.apache).
- The directive itself is documented at [List of php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

About your attempts:

> ```
> ignore_repeated_source 1
> ignore_repeated_source on
> ignore_repeated_source ON
> ignore_repeated_source On
> ```

None of these are listed among the Apache directives defined by `mod_php`, which are these:

```
 php_value name value 
 php_flag name on|off 
 php_admin_value name value 
 php_admin_flag name on|off
```

You should be getting a `500 Server Error` status code and an clear error message in the Apache logs. If you don't, there's possibly something wrong with your Apache set up.

> ```
> php_value ignore_repeated_errors on
> php_value ignore_repeated_source on
> ```

These directives are documented like this:

```
ignore_repeated_errors boolean 
ignore_repeated_source boolean
```

I haven't tested this but you should be getting the original values in e.g. `phpinfo()`. Boolean directives are set with the `php_..._flag` directives.

Comment: hi alvaro, thanks for your answer. I ve read runtime config, php.ini  before. Dueto your advise i read  'php as an apache'. But i dont get any new information out of it. I have done phpinfo() and checked the php.ini . Within the php.ini i have set the ignore_repeated_errors && ignore_repeated_source On ... as it was set to Off before.. but even the change within the php.ini does not fix my problem. The log_errors still catches iterating errors.